# the type of column "column1" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started writing in SQL three months, so constantly learning new things. This one doesnt seem to be doing what I want. I tried casting all the columns and getting rid of the null values, but still it doesnt do what I want. Does anybody have an idea?

```
    SELECT*
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT  
    CAST([Check] AS varchar(255)) AS 'Check',
    CAST([today] AS varchar(255)) AS 'Today',
    CAST(Filenr AS varchar(255)) AS 'Filenr',
    CAST([FileInsertDate] AS varchar(255)) AS 'FileInsertDate',
    CAST([column1] AS varchar(255)) AS 'column1',
    CAST([column2] AS varchar(255)) AS 'column2',
    CAST([column3] AS varchar(255)) AS 'column3'
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT  
    [Check],
    [today],
    Filenr,
    [FileInsertDate],
    CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 'no value' ELSE [column1] END AS 'column1',
    [column2],
    [column3]
 FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
'Country field' AS 'Check',
cast (GETDATE() as DATE) AS [Today],
  t1.Filenr,
  t1.FileInsertDate,
  t2.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS      AS column1,
  t3.name                                                   AS column2,
  t4.column3

FROM [table1]                           t1
LEFT JOIN [table2]                      t2
  ON t2.Case_FileNumber = t1.Filenr COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
LEFT JOIN [table3]                          t3
  ON t3.code = t1.code
LEFT JOIN [table4]                  t4
  ON t1.code = t4.code

WHERE t1.FileInsertDate > '20170101'
)A
WHERE column1<>column2
    )B
        )C
    UNPIVOT (
              ValueNaam For KeyNaam IN ([Today],
                                        filenr,
                                        [FileInsertDate],
                                        column1,
                                        column2,
                                        column3)
       )D
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The change of the collation for col1 is causing the problem:

```
t2.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS column1,
```

After the final cast to `varchar(255)`, all columns for the unpivot are of type `varchar(255)` and all of them in the collation of the db 'database_default' **except** `col1` which is of a different collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

You could fix that by explicitly defining the collation of col1:

-- >= SQL Server 2016

```
    CAST([column1] AS varchar(255)) collate database_default AS 'column1',
    --or depending on the query 
    --CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 'no value' ELSE [column1] END collate database_default AS 'column1',
```

-- SQL Server 2016 > ... >= SQL Server 2012

```
    CAST(formatmessage('%s', [column1]) AS varchar(255)) /*collate database_default*/ AS 'column1',
    --CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 'no value' ELSE formatmessage('%s', [column1]) END collate database_default AS 'column1',
```

-- SQL Server 2008

```
    CAST('' as xml).value('sql:column("column1")', 'varchar(255)') as 'column1'
    --CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 'no value' ELSE cast('' as xml).value('sql:column("column1")', 'varchar(255)') END collate database_default AS 'column1',
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the code to: CAST([column1] AS varchar(255)) collate database_default AS 'column1'. But now i get the following error message:COLLATE clause cannot be used on expressions containing a COLLATE clause.

Comment: @laura, check your sqlserver version and use the corresponding query